# Meteor IronRouter waitOn Infinite loop

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I have a pretty standard setup for my meteor app using IronRouter. What I am having problems with is this, I am attempting to redirect someone to a page based on some tokens in a url coming from a third party website but when the user is sent to their destination from the Accounts.onLogin callback via Router.go("some/fun/url"); the waitOn function runs endlessly.
Below is the pertinent part of the setup.

First the route that I am redirecting to:

```
Router.route("/shows/:show_acronym/sponsorships", {
    name:"sponsorshipsSalesPortal",
    data:function(){
        return {show:Shows.findOne({acronym:this.params.show_acronym})};
    },
    waitOn:function(){
        console.log("wait on");

        return [Meteor.subscribe("show_by_acronym",this.params.show_acronym),Meteor.subscribe("catalogue_products_by_acronym", this.params.show_acronym)];

    }
});
```

Next the relevant part of the onLogin hook:

```
Accounts.onLogin(function(){
    if (Session.get("showToRedirectTo")){
      console.log("sending to sponsorship portal");
      var ur ="/shows/"+Session.get("showToRedirectTo")+"/sponsorships"

      return Router.go(ur);
    }
});
```

When it hits the redirect, the url changes and the message "wait on" prints in the console forever. Does anyone know of a solution to this? I would prefer to keep all of my subscriptions at the router level if at all possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should only return subscription cursors (Meteor.subscribe(*)) in the waitOn return array.
In your case, "this.params.show_acronym" is the problem...

Answer (score 0):

Actually your code looks good, its been a while since i dont use Iron Router or Sessions.

But looking at the WaitOn, it seems okay, the problem can come from the Server side where `show_by_acronym` or `catalogue_products_by_acronym` its throwing an error, but in all the cases this should cause you to get a `spinner` loading forever, not a `console.log("wait on");` printed forever.

so i think your `Accounts.onLogin` is causing this.

Try something like.

```
Accounts.onLogin(function(){
    if (Session.get("showToRedirectTo")){
      console.log("sending to sponsorship portal");
      var ur ="/shows/"+Session.get("showToRedirectTo")+"/sponsorships"

      Router.go(ur);
      Session.set('showToRedirectTo', false)
    }
});
```